# Probability of two random variables

Tags: probability

So I have two independent random variables $X$ and $Y$. $X$ is a $\operatorname{Binomial}(4, \frac{1}{3})$ while $Y$ is a $\operatorname{Geometric}(\frac{1}{3})$. I should calculate $P(Y^2 \geq X)$.

Can someone explain the process to solve this? Thanks

Comment: Hint: $P(Y^2=X) = P(Y^2-X=0)=P(Y^2 + (-X) = 0)$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is difficult (you have two random variables!) but with only one random variable it would have been easier. So one way to simplify the problem is by the law of total probability:

$$P(Y^2>X)=\sum\limits_{k=0}^4 \Pr(Y^2>X\vert X=k)\Pr(X=k)$$

The second part is simply using the formula for Binomial distribution, so lets focus on the conditional probability. In general, if $Z\sim Geom (p)$ then $\Pr(Z>n)=(1-p)^n$ for integers (use the definition of $n$ failures or compute the entire sum). We can use it to compute all the probabilities:

- $\Pr(Y^2>0)=1$
- Note that the event $Y^2>1$ implies $Y>1$. Same goes for $2,3$, since if $Y=1$ then $Y^2<2,3$ but for higher values of $Y$, $Y^2>2,3$. Thus, $\Pr(Y>k)=1-p$ for $k=1,2,3$.
- $\Pr(Y^2>4)=\Pr(Y>2)=(1-p)^2$

Finally,

$$P(Y^2>X)={4 \choose 0}\tfrac{2^{4}}{3^4}+\left({4 \choose 1}\tfrac{2^{4-1}}{3^4}+{4 \choose 2}\tfrac{2^{4-2}}{3^4}+{4 \choose 3}\tfrac{2^{4-3}}{3^4}\right)\tfrac{2}{3}+{4 \choose 4}\tfrac{1}{3^4}\left(\tfrac{2}{3}\right)^2 =
\tfrac{2^{4}}{3^4}+\left(4\tfrac{2^{4-1}}{3^4}+6\tfrac{2^{4-2}}{3^4}+6\tfrac{2^{4-3}}{3^4}\right)\tfrac{2}{3}+\tfrac{1}{3^4}\left(\tfrac{2}{3}\right)^2=0.76 $$

**Edit** Sorry, just noticed that I've solved it for $Y>X$ and not $Y\geq X$. To solve the original idea you can use the same idea, with small adjustments (this time, $\Pr(Y\geq n)=(1-p)^{n+1}$)

Answer (score 1):

First condition on one of them. For example, try $P\left(Y \geq \sqrt{X}\,|\,X\right)$; since $Y$ is geometric you don't need to consider the case where $Y$ is negative. This calculation will treat $X$ as a fixed constant, so the result will be an expression that depends on $X$ in some way, but no longer has any dependence on $Y$. You can then take an expectation of this quantity, using the property that, for any event $E$,

$$P\left(E\right) = E\left(P\left(E\,|\,X\right)\right).$$

The above property is just as valid if you replace $X$ by $Y$ in the conditioning. Often, conditioning on one of the random variables will result in a much simpler calculation than conditioning on the other one. If it is not obvious which one to condition on, you should try both and see.

Answer (score 1):

Since $X,Y$ are independent, and $0\leqslant X\leqslant 4$ is certain, then we may partition the probability space over $\{\{Y=0\},\{Y=1\},\{Y\geqslant 2\}\}$, to evaluate: $$\begin{align}\mathsf P(X\leqslant Y^2)~&=~{\mathsf P(X = 0^2)\,\mathsf P(Y=0)+\mathsf P(X\leqslant 1^2)\,\mathsf P(Y=1)+\mathsf P(X\leqslant 4)\,\mathsf P(Y\geqslant 2)}\end{align}$$